# get_the_post_thumbnail gives wrong absolute url

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My job is to migrate a wordpress page localhost to production environment.

There is a problem with images, the symptoms are the following: 
A simple request like: `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(75, 75), array('class' => "grid-item-content-icon"));` gives me an absolute url, witch is the following:

```
<img 
    src="http://localhost/*some name*/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stock-photo-a-group-of-tiny-people-walking-towards-a-light-bulb-95035678-90x90.jpg" 
    class="grid-item-content-icon wp-post-image" 
    alt="stock-photo-a-group-of-tiny-people-walking-towards-a-light-bulb-95035678">
```

I figure out, the source of the problem is the `get_the_post_thumbnail`, witch give me a bad url. I cannot found any key in the `wp_options` table that related on this issue. The `site_url` and the `home` options are set properly.

Anybody has a same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked your config see if the url is hard coded also check the `wp_options` db table for `siteurl` option (first entry) they'll need updating to your non local url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hardly explainable situation caused this problem. The wordress was hardened, so the `wp-content/uploads` directory is not writable (by Apache). I tried, what happens if I upload an image, and it works fine. Suddenly the previews are working and images appears.

Answer (score 0):

Update your featured images on live site so it will not point to the localhost any more.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the Site url in your Database. Login to your database and run the following query:

```
Select * from wp_options where option_name= 'siteurl' // change the value of option_value to your current live site URL
```

same process for this query too..

```
Select * from wp_options where option_name= 'home'
```

NOTE:You need to change your site URL while shifting form local to live otherwise it will point you to the local.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but as I wrote in the question, the `home` and `siteurl` keys on wp_options are set properly.

Comment: The solution was in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278647/1234441 (I can't accept my answer for a while)

Answer (score 0):

get_the_post_thumbnail, Thumbnail URL

```
<?php
            //Get the Thumbnail URL
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 720,405 ), false, '' );
            echo $src[0];
            ?>
```

link image file  : http://localhost:8888/app/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image-1.png